# Spanning Set of Null Space of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, span

I'm having a tough time finding any resources online or even in my book that give me a good way to solve problems like the one I have. I have a couple like it, so if someone could explain generally while explaining the given example, it would be greatly appreciated. The question is

```
    "Determine a spanning set for the null space of the given matrix A."

    A = {{1,2,3,5},{1,3,4,2},{2,4,6,-1}}.
```

Seems like it would be a simple enough problem, I know some of what to do but it doesn't seem systematic or reliable, and it hasn't worked for every problem, so I must be doing something wrong. Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: You picture doesn't include the whole question.

Comment: It does. It's straight out of the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First reduce it to RREC:
$$ A' = \begin{bmatrix}
1 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\
0 && 1 && 1 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now lets find vectors $v = [w, x, y, z]$ that satisfy $vA = 0$
$$ w + y = 0 $$
$$ x + y = 0 $$
$$ z = 0 $$
Then, solving for $w, x, z$: $w = -y, x = -y, z = 0$.

Hence $[-y, -y, y, 0] \in \mathrm{Null}(A)$. From that you can conclude $\mathrm{span}([-1, -1, 1, 0]) = \mathrm{Null}(A)$.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm confused on how this works for other problems. Assuming a matrix has an RREC of {{1,0,-1},{0,1,2},{0,0,0}}, then how could we possibly arrive at any other solution than ([0,0,0]) with that method of solving? I see your logic for the given problem, but applying it, you would get r=0, s=0, and t=2s. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @RoryHector If you plug $[x, y, z]$ into that matrix, you get $x + z = 0$, $y - 2z = 0$.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be ___x - z = 0 and y + 2z = 0___ _?_ Which, if that were the case, I believe would leave you with the answer ___([1,-2,0])___.

Comment: @RoryHector That was a typo.

Comment: @RoryHector Yes.